# how to run this flag in IOS tests, --test-targets?

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to run the xctest tests for IOS, but I have a problem when I want to run a single class, in the testlab firebase, but all the classes that I have in my project are still running, and I need to run a single class, this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you're using the `gcloud` command-line tool to create your test matrix.

Specify the tests you wish to run in a copy of your .xctestrun file (same as how you would do this when running tests locally using XCode), and pass that modified xctestrun file using:

`gcloud firebase test ios run  --test=<your test zip>  --xctestrun-file=<your customized .xctestrun file>`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I completely understand your question, but i think what you are looking for is this:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace [MyApplication.xcworkspace] -scheme [yourScheme] -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=11.4' -only-testing:[Target/Class/testExample]
```

Where you do not have to enter testExample, only class and it will run whole class, and if you add /testMethod it will run only that test. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) you can check for more info.

Another way would be creating a scheme where you would select only tests you want to run, and then you would run only that scheme. Its pretty simple to do too. Take a look here: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2016/04/06/Testing-Schemes/